# When I minimize my web page everything is messed up

Tags: html, css

for a school project I must make a webpage about my self, the web page is in Dutch, it is not completed, but I have done a lot an the webpage is almost done, the only problem is that when I minimize my page everything(text, photos, div, banners etc..) is going to be in another place and getting other measurements.
**Could an expert watch and control/correct what I did wrong so I can finally end my site?**
**Or could you explain me why is it happening?**
I will attach my site in a zip folder.
**[Here:](http://www.filedropper.com/site_5)** http://www.filedropper.com/site_5
Thanks in advance.
PS: This is not my real site, but a copy. In the folder you will find photos, style sheets, and html-code all together.

Comment: Look up responsive design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use something like Normalise or Reset css, because it looks different on IE/webkit/FF
2. you need to use media queries (there are many good tutorials on the web), you don't need to use many of them, only basic breakpoints, so you arrange content that doesn't fit
3. you can't use margins to define main content area, that's why your margin-left/right 400px causes shrinking of content area. Use width 1120px for content (on FullHD screen, use media queries for smaller resolutions) and give it `margin: 0 auto;` - it will align it to center of body
4. when you're using resize effect on buttons, make sure you count with bigger value, so after resize the button will not move other elements (you can find tutorials for this too)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked; "width: 1085px;
    margin: 0 auto;"

Answer (score -2):

All I really see on the site is that when I make the window smaller the button moves too a different line.

You could wrap the page in a table;

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
<table width="80%" align="center">
<tr>
<div id="welkomachtergrond"></div>
</tr>
<tr>
        <div id="welkomtext" align="center">
            WELKOM
        </div>
</tr>
<tr>
        <div id="welkomtext2">
            <center>BY</center>
            <p><center>Federico xxx</center></p>
        </div>
</tr>
<tr colspan="4">
        <td><a ID="GhostButton" href="OverMij.html">Overmij</a></td>
        <td><a ID="GhostButton1" href="Foto.html">Foto's</a></td>
        <td><a ID="GhostButton2" href="Video.html">Video's</a></td>
        <td><a ID="GhostButton3" href="Contact.html">Contact</a></td>
</tr>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You could also change that width to an exact pixel number and center the table then.

Comment: The width and align attribute on the table element is obsolete..and watch your uppercases. Welcome to the 21st century :)

Comment: The All caps were from the original index file provided above :) and it still works in HTML 5 afaik